# Unable to get the "per thousand" symbol printed

Tags: textcomp

I am using PcTeX and in a document with the following preamble

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

I've tried to use the `\textperthousand` command.

When I do the typesetting I get the message

> No font mapping entry for font: tcrm1000”

and no per thousand symbol.

How do I get the per thousand symbol in my document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that the fonts cmsuper are missing. You can install it or try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

\textperthousand

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I include \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and \usepackage{modern} all the mathematical expressions go wrong, really wrong!

Comment: I cannot see it. Give more informations!